# Identify if a user has already seen this part of the map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm currently developing an application and am hitting a brick wall in annotation performance.

Currently, I have this code:

```
-(void) getStationsWithRadius:(float)distance //distanceInMetres
{
    distance = (distance/1000.0f);
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[mkMapView centerCoordinate].latitude longitude:[mkMapView centerCoordinate].longitude];
    ///....Network stuff....
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{

    MKMapRect mRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;
    MKMapPoint eastMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));
    MKMapPoint westMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));

    zoomDistance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(eastMapPoint, westMapPoint); //In Meters
    [self getAnnotationsWithRadius:zoomDistance];
//etc.....
```

In a nutshell, every time the user changes region on the Map, I'd like the application to query the server to get annotations based on the center of the `MKMapView` co-ordinates and the zoom distance (radius).

This is obviously very tolling on the server, as even the slightest variation in map movement will cause the application to request annotations.

Is there a way to identify if the user has already loaded the annotations for the map view they are currently on?

Answer (score 0):

Request the annotations by bounding rect, not by center and radius. Store all annotations you receive, indexed by both x and y points. Store the rectangles you’ve requested annotations for in a smart structure that will merge rectangles that form larger rectangles.

Whenever the user moves the map you just check your structure to see if everything inside the current area has been requested, and if so just look up all the annotations in the x range and in the y range and logically AND them together.

If not, fetch the annotations in the part(s) of the rect you’re missing, and mark that you’ve now fetched that rect.